# How to get back a file that was excluded from a build configuration in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse, configuration, eclipse-cdt

Using Indigo and a managed build C++ project, I right-clicked on a source file and selected `Resource Configurations->Exclude From Build...`, and the file promptly disappears. Scrolling down shows it at the bottom of the list of source files with a new dimmed icon. Now how do I get it back? The `Reset to Default...` option is always dimmed out. Right-clicking on the excluded file still only shows the `Exclude From Build...` option. Is there an `Include in Build` option somewhere?  I realize I can go to .cproject file and manually edit it back in but I figure there must be a way to do it from the IDE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In eclipse there's not a similar way to reinclude resource, like:

- Resource Configuration -> Reinclude from build

You need to go in Project Proprerties (Alt+Enter) and go:

```
C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols
```

Select tab

```
Source Location
```

and expand your project's folder: here you can select filter that you want to remove and click on "**Edit Filter**" and then "**Remove**".

Comment: Excellent! I marked this as the answer since this was originally what I was after. However, I still think I'll use my work-around.

Comment: oh yes, your solution is very usefull when you have not too much files!

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @Velthune.  the changes are not visible unless, we refresh the project, upon which the cross marks against the files list are gone.  Eclipse cdt need a way to reinstate the excluded files with other better option..

Answer (score 14):

Yes this is an old question. But people do go looking for answers years later..

There's an easy way, but it's counter intuitive. Right click the excluded item, select "exclude from build", and on the dialog that appears, **uncheck** the builds for which you'd like the item back. Note the convenient 'Deselect All' button.

Comment: I found this to be slightly quicker than the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you!! This had me stuck hard for almost ten minutes, thank you Jeff

Answer (score 1):

While I still don't know how get back a file that's been excluded. I have discovered that it's much better to just add a new folder, and then mark the folder as excluded. Then files can be excluded by dragging them into this folder and included back by dragging them back to the original folder.