# Remove exclusion in C++ project

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have C++ project in Eclipse. Several project files are located in sub directory that I'm trying to add to includes. Because of unknown reason directory is visible with strange icon that means "excluded from build". I did not set such parameter. How to disable "exclusion" on this folder?

[image]

Comment: Is that helpful: [How to get back a file that was excluded from a build configuration in Eclipse CDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964469/how-to-get-back-a-file-that-was-excluded-from-a-build-configuration-in-eclipse-c?)

Comment: Another place to look is File Properties -> C/C++ Build -> "Exclude resource from build" checkbox.